# snmp4j agent/manager for v3 handling

Tags: java, snmp

I am new to snmp and trying to review the theoretical concepts now. I have an existing application written using a library:

[snmp java library](https://github.com/jitlogic/libsnmp/tree/master/src/main/java/com/jitlogic/contrib/libsnmp)

This library allows for v1 and v2 handling. The application basically sends out alerts & was designed & developed with no documentation available. I have to figure out a way to accommodate v3 and my initial view is that I would need to code something from scratch. Could someone clarify what the major differences are between v3 and the others? I do understand security and encryption are the main features, but other than that what else should I focus on? Also with the security feature of authentication does this only involve username/password or can we implement this too with certificates?

Could someone recommend a tutorial / example to test snmp on a windows 10 desktop installation with perhaps some other server/machine on the network?

Comment: https://www.snmp4j.org/ may be more productive for you

Comment: Thanks; looking into that.